# Grab the middle x results, based on key result in an elegant way

Tags: php, structured-array

I have a set of products.  Based on the state of the page, I'm displaying one product and then up to 4 other products.  The result set of the products can be any size greater than 5 products.  I want to ALWAYS show 5 products.  If available I want to show the 2 products below(in the result set) and the 2 products above.

Examples:

If there are 10 results and the key product is 5.  I want to show 3,4,5,6,7.

If there are 10 results and the key product is 9.  I want to show 6,7,8,9,10.

If there are 10 results and the key product is 1.  I want to show 1,2,3,4,5.

Right now I'm using min() and max() and some "IF"s to figure it out and it takes a ridiculous number of lines of code, when there is an elegant solution out there, I'm just not finding it!
example array result set below

```
$similar_products = array(
  array(
    "id" => 1,
    "title" => "Product One"
  ),
  array(
    "id" => 2,
    "title" => "Product Two"
  ),
  array(
    "id" => 3,
    "title" => "Product Three"
  ),
  array(
    "id" => 4,
    "title" => "Product Four"
  ),
  array(
    "id" => 5,
    "title" => "Product Five"
  ),
  array(
    "id" => 6,
    "title" => "Product Six"
  ),
  array(
    "id" => 7,
    "title" => "Product Seven"
  ),
  array(
    "id" => 8,
    "title" => "Product Eight"
  ),
  array(
    "id" => 9,
    "title" => "Product Nine"
  ),
  array(
    "id" => 10,
    "title" => "Product Ten"
  )
);
$i = 8; //change this value to test different key product array positions
$arrOut = array();
$floor = 0;
if($i <= 1) { //the key product is either in the first or second position in the array
  $floor = 0;
  $arrOut[] = $similar_products[0];
  $arrOut[] = $similar_products[1];
  $arrOut[] = $similar_products[2];
  $arrOut[] = $similar_products[3];
  $arrOut[] = $similar_products[4];
} elseif((count($similar_products)-1)-$i <= 1) {  //the key product is either in the last or second to last in the array
  $floor = count($similar_products)-5;
  $arrOut[] = $similar_products[count($similar_products)-5];
  $arrOut[] = $similar_products[count($similar_products)-4];
  $arrOut[] = $similar_products[count($similar_products)-3];
  $arrOut[] = $similar_products[count($similar_products)-2];
  $arrOut[] = $similar_products[count($similar_products)-1];
} else {  //otherwise, just grab two above and two below
  $floor = $i-2;
  $arrOut[] = $similar_products[$i-2];
  $arrOut[] = $similar_products[$i-1];
  $arrOut[] = $similar_products[$i];
  $arrOut[] = $similar_products[$i+1];
  $arrOut[] = $similar_products[$i+2];
}
$x = $floor;  //set x, our counter, to the floor (floor = the very first output postion)
foreach($arrOut as $ao) {
  if($x == $i) {  //current key product
    echo "<strong>" . $ao['id'] . ":" . $ao['title'] . "</strong><hr/>";
  } else {  //other NON key products
    echo $ao['id'] . ":" . $ao['title'] . "<hr/>";
  }
  $x++;
}
```

Comment: Is your code readable and performant enough? Then there is no problem and does not really fit SO questions. Also, in general you should show the actual code you have now.

Comment: I added the code I wanted.  I'd like the ability to reset the number of products from 5 to any number less than the total number of products in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want you can remove the variable config, condense it a bit, and make it a 1-liner ;-)
I'm not good with this stuff, so there are probably more efficient and/or shorter options.

```
// Set array index, starts with 0
// If you need to find with specific ID, just find the index by the ID
$primaryIndex = 4;// change this number to test

// How many extra items to show
// Must be divisible by 2
$extraToShow = 4;

// Find total items available - 1 to work with array indexes
$maxIndex = count($similar_products) - 1;

// Find the slice start
$low = min($maxIndex - $extraToShow, max(0, $primaryIndex - 1 - $extraToShow / 2));

// Slice to needed
$items = array_slice($similar_products, $low, $extraToShow + 1);

var_dump($items);
```

Comment: This is perfect.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// example code
$productKey = 7;
$resultsShown = 5; 
$totalResults = 10;//num_rows()?
$limit = floor($resultsShown/2);
$min = $limit;
$max = $totalResults - $limit;
if($productKey<=$min){
for($i = 1;$i<=$resultsShown; $i++){
//Display result
echo $i;
}
}
else if($productKey>$max){
for( $i = $totalResults - $resultsShown+1; $i <=$totalResults;$i++){
//Display result
echo $i;
}}
else{
for( $i = $productKey - $limit; $i<=$productKey + $limit; $i++){
//Display result
echo $i;
}
}
```

Haven't had chance to test as I'm on mobile, but the simplest way I could think to solve the problem while giving you chance to change those fixed limits in the future, not elegant, but can't see what you have at the moment to compare!